# SQLite 3 and Odbc Data Srource Name

Tags: c#, sqlite, odbc, sqlconnection

Respect,

How to connect sqlite database from c# over Odbc connection string. I want to connect over data srouce name so I dont want use absolute path for DB. I have created ODBC DSN with Data Soruce Name "TestOdbc" and Data Base Name is full path to my sqlite test.db whic is located at C:\Test\test.db. In test.db is one table TestTable with few records.

I try to use ODBCConnection in c# and SqliteConnection too but I have no luck. With SqliteConnection I establish connection but but the connection was not established to C:\Test\test.db I think new database is created only in :memory because when I try to select records from TestTable I got error that table does not exist.

Please any sugesstion?

Code:

```
try
        {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Datasource=TestOdbc;";
            conn.Open();

            SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";
            SQLiteDataReader created = comm.ExecuteReader();
            comm.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("connection opened!!!");
        }
        catch(SQLiteException ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 //create table and insert data 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // We use these three SQLite objects:
                SQLiteConnection conn;
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
                SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

                // create a new database connection:
                conn = new SQLiteConnection("Driver = SQLite3 ODBC Driver; Datasource = TestOdbc;Version = 3;New=True;Compress=True;");

                // open the connection:
                conn.Open();

                // create a new SQL command:
                sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test2 (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));";

                // Now lets execute the SQL ;D
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Lets insert something into our new table:
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test2 (id, text) VALUES (1, 'Test Text 1');";

                // And execute this again ;D
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                label4.Text = "test2";
                label5.Text = "TestOdbc";
                // We are ready, now lets cleanup and close our connection:
                conn.Close();
            }

 //show inseted value from sqlite 



     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Datasource=TestOdbc;Version = 3;New=True;Compress=True;";
                    conn.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand();
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test2";
                    SQLiteDataReader created = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("connection opened!!!");
                    while (created.Read()) // Read() returns true if there is still a result line to read
                    {
                    // Print out the content of the text field:
                    string myreader = "";
                    try
                    {
                        myreader = created[1].ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    label3.Text="  "+myreader;
                }
                comm.Dispose();
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

[image]